# Collapse variables into one variable with values preserving the variable names

Tags: r, reshape

After merging two data frames, I get this:

```
d.f <- data.frame(sex = c("M", "F", NA, NA),
       age = c(NA, NA, "old", "young"),
       n = c(2, 1, 3, 4))
```

...but would like to combine the first two variables into one, and end up with this:

```
sex.age      n
 sex.M       2
 sex.F       1
 age.old     3
 age.young   4
```

It seems like a simple (and probably common) problem, but I am really struggling to find the answer. I thought there is something ready made along the lines of tidyr and reshape, but I am not finding it - probably because the resulting structure is very untidy.

The data structure will stay the same, meaning that NA's are always in different rows. Solutions like

```
na.omit(unlist(d.f[1:2]))
```

or

```
apply(d.f[, 1:2], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

do work, but there is no easy way to get the variable names prefixes.

Comment: I would argue that data structure is not at all "common" and represents a pathological situation.

Comment: It is an outcome of `list(data.frame(sex = c("M", "F"), n = c(2,1)),
     data.frame(age = c("old", "young"), n = c(3,4))) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows()` , so not entirely unreasonable. It is interesting to note that `data.table::rbindlist()` deals with the situation by collapsing NAs, and keeping the first variable name. Don't know what to conclude, would like to hear other opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `dplyr/tidyr`.  We covert the 'wide' to 'long' format with `gather`, `unite` the columns 'Var' and 'Val' to create 'sex.age' and rearrange the column order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(d.f, Var, Val, -n, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
                 unite(sex.age, Var, Val, sep=".") %>%
                 select(2:1)
#    sex.age n
#1     sex.M 2
#2     sex.F 1
#7   age.old 3
#8 age.young 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` from the reshape2 package.

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(d.f, id.vars = "n")
df[!is.na(df$value), ]
#   n variable value
# 1 2      sex     M
# 2 1      sex     F
# 7 3      age   old
# 8 4      age young
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful, but @akrun 's answer gives me the column name I need.